# Как добавить в вызов функции aioshedule вызов другой функции?

Tags: python, asyncio, aiomysql

Есть функция, с помощью которой создаются бэкапы локальной БД, кот. хранится на ПК. Второй функцией необходимо реализовать, чтобы бэкапы создавались по времени - каждый час с помощью aioshedule. Код асинхронный.
Функция для бэкапа:

```
import asyncio
import aiomysql
import time
import datetime
import aioschedule as schedule

# запускаем цикл
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

# наименовываем изначальную бд для простоты обращения
db = 'testbd'


# функция для бэкапа
async def test_example():
    # подключение к серверу

    conn = await aiomysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306,
                                  user='root', password='12345678', db='testbd',
                                  )
    cursor = await conn.cursor()

    # получаем названия всех таблиц в базе
    await cursor.execute('SHOW TABLES;')
    table_names = []
    for record in await cursor.fetchall():
        table_names.append(record[0])

    # здесь должен быть модуль вписывающий добавочным именем дату и время бэкапа

    dateNow = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    backup_dbname = db + '_bp' + '_' + str(dateNow)
    try:
        await cursor.execute(f'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {backup_dbname}')
    except:
        pass

    await cursor.execute(f'USE {backup_dbname}')

    for table_name in table_names:
        await cursor.execute(
            f'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} SELECT * FROM {db}.{table_name}')

    dateNow = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    backup_dbname = db + '_bp2' + '_' + str(dateNow)
    try:
        await cursor.execute(f'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {backup_dbname}')
    except:
        pass

    await cursor.execute(f'USE {backup_dbname}')

    for table_name in table_names:
        await cursor.execute(
            f'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} SELECT * FROM {db}.{table_name}')

    conn.close()

loop.run_until_complete(test_example())
```

Функция для вызова по времени:

```
import asyncio
import time
import aioschedule as schedule


async def job(message='stuff', n=1):
    print("Asynchronous invocation (%s) of I'm working on:" % n, message)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


schedule.every().day.at("23:15").do(job)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
while True:
    loop.run_until_complete(schedule.run_pending())
    time.sleep(0.1)
```